# Pass git stuck options with quotes as-is to a script

Tags: bash, shell, git, shell-script, parameters

I'm trying to write a script that will be called as a git alias.

The script is a wrapper around `git merge`, so I want to pass all it's parameters to `git merge` as-is when I call it in the script.

The alias is set like this:

```
git config alias.my-merge-wrapper  '!f(){ path/to/script.sh $@; }; f'
```

My first try was this:

```
#!/bin/sh
git merge "$@"
```

Sadly, this does not work with *stuck* options (see [here](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/api-parse-options)):

For example, if I call my script like this:

```
git my-merge-wrapper -m"message (b2 into b1)"
```

It fails, because `git merge` is called like this:

```
git merge -mmessage (b2 into b1)
```

So I get `merge: (b2 - not something we can merge`

I also tried with `$*` in both the alias and the script, without success.

Are there any solution to this?

Comment: I doubt that the problem won't occur with `git my-merge-wrapper -m "message (b2 into b1)"`. Apparently the argument `-m"message (b2 into b1)"` gets split into words. To debug this problem, change your `alias` definition to `git config alias.my-merge-wrapper  '!f(){ set -x; path/to/script.sh "$@"; }; f'` and add a line `set -x` in your script after `#!/bin/sh` and copy&paste the output *to your question* you get from running `git my-merge-wrapper -m"message (b2 into b1)"`

Comment: Thank you... I saw elsewhere that I had to use `printf` to debug this, and it misled me, `set -x` is way better... I'll clarify my question and answer it as soon as I can

Comment: It is possible to use `printf` or `echo` for debugging as well, e.g. something like `echo "args:"; for i in "$@"; do echo "$i"; done`. In this case you should show the exact code, the command line and the resulting output. If your script is big you can also use `set -x`/`set +x` selectively to limit the output to a certain part of your script.

Comment: Thank you for your help, actually it's not `printf`'s fault but mine only: when I tested my script I first declared the alias like this: `git config alias.my-merge-wrapper  '!f(){ path/to/script.sh $@; }; f'`, which gave me the `merge: (b2 - not something we can merge` error. To understand what happened I used `printf 'Arg: %s\n' $@` and `printf 'Arg: %s\n' "$@"` but mixed them up, and since I thought that I had to separate `-m` and the message, even when I fixed the alias (just to be sure, I didn't see that the error disappeared), since the printf didn't change I thought I was stuck...

Comment: Anyway, now I don't know what to do with this question...

Comment: (by the way, here is the relevant `set -x` output line: `+ git merge '-mmessage (b2 into b1)'`, I also tried with `git merge -m"message (b2 into b1) -n" -n`, and I got `+ git merge '-mmessage (b2 into b1) -n' -n`, so everything is alright)

Comment: Please don't use comments to provide additional information, [edit] your question instead. (at least the next time) You could either "fix"  your question to show the state before your fix (`path/to/script.sh $@`) that will reproduce the problem and write your fix as an answer yourself, or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to quote `$@` in the alias too:

```
git config alias.my-merge-wrapper  '!f(){ path/to/script.sh "$@"; }; f'
```

Then the git stuck option's short name and its quoted argument are grouped as a unique shell script argument (as if it was `'-mmessage (b2 into b1)'`), but git supports it without problem.